# How to refresh the Kendo UI grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to refresh a Kendo UI grid but have not yet been successful. Would anybody please advise what I missed or what I did wrong?

I have the following code:

**.cshtml:**

```
 $('#btnRefresh').click(function (e){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "@(Url.Content("~/Administration/RefreshAll/"))",

                success: function () {
                    $("#Product").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    $('#Product').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
                    //grid.refresh();
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                error: function (){
                    $("#btnRefresh").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            });


      });
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult RefreshAll([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            db.ProcessAll();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

your **script** should be

```
$('#btnRefresh').click(function (e){
        var grid = $("#Product").data("kendoGrid");
               grid.dataSource.page(1);
               grid.dataSource.read();
      });
```

in your controller **add references** to

- `using Kendo.Mvc.UI;`
- `using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;`

your **ActionResult** should be

```
public ActionResult RefreshAll([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            //assuming db.ProcessAll() will return a list object
            return Json(db.ProcessAll().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

Comment: public void ProcessAll() therefore i could not return as JSON

Comment: You need to pass a list object to model.

Comment: @HaBo Thanks, but this gives "TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined" error. I also looked on many pages and tried different variations of this solution but still get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @chrisrof check your selectors for grid